# Oracle : Need to convert ROWS values into COLUMN

Tags: sql, oracle, case, unpivot

I have multiples records which I want to convert into single column.

I have table which contains records like below.

| id | prjid | studyid | a_udf1 | b_udf1 | a_udf2 | b_udf2 | a_udf3 | b_udf3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | abc | abc | 7-feb-2022 | 7-feb-2022 | chem | chem |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | xyz | xyz | 8-feb-2022 | 8-feb-2022 | polity | null |

and I want result  as below.

| id | prjid | studyid | a_udfvalues | b_udfvalues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | abc | abc |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | 7-feb-2022 | 7-feb-2022 |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | chem | chem |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | xyz | xyz |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | 8-feb-2022 | 8-feb-2022 |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | polity | null |

and so on.

### Oracle Query

```
SELECT id, prjid,studyid,
       CASE
           WHEN Attribute IN (A_UDF1, A_UDF2, A_UDF3, A_UDF4) THEN 'a_values'
           WHEN Attribute IN (B_UDF1, B_UDF2, B_UDF3) THEN 'b_values'
       END AS Category,
       Value
FROM (
    SELECT id, prjid,studyid, A_UDF1, A_UDF2, A_UDF3, B_UDF1, B_UDF2, B_UDF3
    FROM SAMPLE_T
) t
UNPIVOT (
    Value
    FOR Attribute IN (A_UDF1, A_UDF2, A_UDF3, B_UDF1, B_UDF2, B_UDF3)
);
```

I was trying above query but not giving correct result. It is giving result as below

| id | prjid | studyid | a_udfvalues | b_udfvalues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | abc | null |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | 7-feb-2022 | null |
| 1 | 30 | 2 | chem | null |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | null | xyz |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | null | 8-feb-2022 |
| 2 | 12 | 3 | null | polity |

and  so  on.

I  cant filter "NULL" values because sometimes columns may contain null values in that case if i filter null values it will get missing from result.
Can somebody please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the below:

```
select id, prj_id, study_id, a_udf1 a_udfvalues, b_udf1 b_udfvalues
from sample_t
union all
select id, prj_id, study_id, a_udf2 a_udfvalues, b_udf2 b_udfvalues
from sample_t
union all
select id, prj_id, study_id, a_udf3 a_udfvalues, b_udf3 b_udfvalues
from sample_t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach. In above case a_udf1 or b_udf1 columns will be increasing. I mean UDF columns are not fixed I can be a_udf1 to a_udf15 so in that case code length will get increased.

Comment: Regarding your latest reply: you definitely have a finite number of columns, so that, even if the length of the code will increase, it will be manageable. There is also the unpivot, but even that requires specific code for each of the columns which you wish to unpivot, and, as you have seen, produces also nulls. But you may eliminate nulls from the result of that unpivot if that is what you wish - only, if there happen to be null values in the initial data, those too will be eliminated.

Comment: Yes I tried this and it is working for me. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/21139120/bogdan-dincescu